# CentOS 7 Server: What is the recommended way of updating WordPress?

Tags: server

I am new to Linux and have got myself a CentOS 7 VPS. Through tutorials, I have managed to install Apache, PHP and MariaDb.

My site is up and running, but I cannot update WordPress or its plugins. I get:

> ERROR: There was an error connecting to the server, Please verify the settings are correct.

I looked up the error and apparently, it is to do with permissions, but I am not sure how to fix!

I have already tried:

```
chown -R mysite-user:apache /var/www/html/mysite.co.uk
```

And when I do `ls -l` on `/var/www/html` I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 mysite-user apache 4096 Mar 13 09:54 mysite.co.uk
```

I have two questions.

**Q1.** What is the recommended way (safest) for allowing WordPress to update its things? Apparently there are two ways, one involving giving Direct access to file system

**Q2.** What are the steps for the answer to Q1?